# showing cmd terminal in qt widgets application

Tags: c++, qt, cmd, console

I'm trying to pass some cmd commands using system() and I would like to be able to "communicate" with cmd, say I code in `system("dir")` in my mainwindow.cpp under my clicked function

this is what it looks like for example

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_login_clicked()
{
  std::string platform_server_ip  = ui->lineEdit_platform_server_ip->text().toStdString();   

  if (platform_server_ip == "dir"

    {
      QMessageBox::information(this,"Login", "all required log in details are correct");

     close();

     const char* c = platform_server_ip.c_str();
     system(c);
     system("ipconfig");


    }
```

*I would like to know why it behaves like this and if that's normal*. I've included  `CONFIG   += console`
in my project file, and checked "run in terminal" (tried it also without) but it never shows me my **desired outcome**.

Instead what I get, is a blank terminal that pops up along side my GUI, and then when I enter "dir" in my GUI and hit enter, a cmd window pops up really fast and in less than a second, its gone. I've even tried it with `system("ipconfig")`and`system ("pause")` 
as well as with one system command like this `system("ipconfig" "&pause")`

**desired outcome:** is just a normal execution of system("ipconfig"), followed by other system commands, that display the same result as typing them in cmd itself.

I've also tried all this in "qt Console application" and I either get the same result, or the output (what would normally be as output on cmd) is then found in "application output" of qt creator.

Is there another better way I can achieve what I want? 
I'm truly a noob and would really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
system("cmd /k ipconfig");
```

This will open another terminal window which will stay open (`k` stands for `keep`) at the end of the command execution.

I think you don't need the `CONFIG += console` project setting, to achieve this. Calling `system` will start another process, which isn't related at all with the calling application.

If you want to start external programs from within a Qt application, you can use [QProcess class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html), which lets you somehow interact with the started processes through standard in/out. For a very simple example, have a form with a push button and a text edit called `textEdit`; in the push button `clicked` slot:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("ipconfig");
process.waitForReadyRead();
ui->textEdit->setText(process.readAll());
process.waitForFinished();
```

This way, you won't see additional console windows, and the command output will be shown directly in your text edit.

This can be generalized in a function like this:

```
bool exec(QString command)
{
  QProcess process;
  process.start(command);
  if(!process.waitForStarted())
  {
    return false; //the process failed to start
  }

  //etc...

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. however.. it just worked today.. without changing anything, my code worked.. the only thing I did differently was (this is gonna sound ridiculous) I clicked on "run" instead of f5...i Honestly have no idea what happened

Comment: hey, i've been trying the code that you provided me with (I think its a thousand times better than what I have!!) and I have a question, is there a way I can input things too? through a line edit? for example input things like "dir" and have them be displayed in my textEdit field? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @skdadle yes you can. I added a generic function to the answer to show how.

Comment: thanks for the edit!! but what about when i want to pass parameters to my batch scripts? (that are in my qprocess commands) for example i would like to pass a username and password from my QLine edits input into this qprocess

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether this is not just a quick hack/tool, you can look at QProcess for more indepth control over your process so that you can read / write the child process pipes.